# Calculate month with days in javascript

Tags: javascript, validation, date, javascript-framework, extjs4.2

I want to calculate month with days in javascript.

I have requirement like My date range will be within 24 months.

I have `todate` comes from somewhere that is 24 Sep 2012

Now,

if I enter 31 Aug 2010 in from date and 24 Sep 2012 in `todate`, it shows an error message.

Currently I am doing like that

`todate.getMonth() - fromdate.getMonth() + (12 * (todate.getFullYear() - fromdate.getFullYear()))`

but, 
if I enter 23 Sep 2010 in from date and 24 Sep 2012, it should also show error message..

but, its allowing me that date..which is 24 month beyond date..so, how can I calculate month with date which does not allow my above given date.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please not use numbers instead of words like to? It is VERY confusing. _as I have 2 show 2 years/24 months data_ means what?

Comment: @mplungjan..hey, thanks for your suggestions...

I have requirement like My date range will be within 24 months

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference in Months between two dates in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536379/difference-in-months-between-two-dates-in-javascript)

Comment: `months = moment(from).diff(moment(to), "months")`

Comment: @thg456 what is moment ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that when it's the same month two years apart, you need to also check the day of the month.

```
function isValidDate (from, to) {
  var months = to.getMonth() - from.getMonth() + 
              (12 * (to.getFullYear() - from.getFullYear()));
  return months < 24 || months === 24 && to.getDate() < from.getDate();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get Days

---

```
function finddays(date_from, date_to) 
{return Math.round(Math.abs(new Date(date_from).getTime() - new Date(date_to).getTime())/(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))}
```

**use:**

> finddays("23 Sep 2010", "25 Sep 2010");

**Update**

Not Recommending but works  better 
**Try this to get months** (hopes a month of 30 days , Error prone +-3/yr)

---

```
 function findMonths(date_from, date_to) 
    {return Math.round((new Date(date_to).getTime()-new Date(date_from).getTime())/(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24*30))}
```

**use:**

> findMonths("23 Sep 2010", "25 Oct 2010");

Comment: But he is looking for findmonths, not finddays