# Auto populating the textbox after calculating the date difference

Tags: javascript

I have two text boxes in my application. In the first text box user enters the date in yyyy/mm/dd format. Then I need to take the system date and find the difference between the two dates in months, which I am able to do it using javascript. Now I need to populate the second text box with that difference.
How this can be achieved?

Comment: I see no code. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (calculates difference in msecs):

**EDIT** re-written for `onkeyup` event

HTML:

```
<input id="initialDate" onkeyup="checkDiff(this.value)"/>
<input id="diff"/>
```

JS:

```
function checkDiff (initialDate) {
    if (initialDate.length == 10){
        var dateParts = initialDate.split("/");
        var date = new Date(dateParts[0], dateParts[1]-1,dateParts[2]);
        var diff = document.getElementById('diff');
        var now = new Date();
        diff.value = (now-date);
    }
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8haJX/

Comment: i need to do this without having a button click.How can I achieve this.

Comment: what event do you want to use in such a case?

Comment: That is what i am thinking to implement i am not getting any thing.Please suggest me

Comment: If you don't like buttons, you can use `onKeyUp` event. I've edited answer accordingly

Comment: this is exactly what I am looking for. I need to populate the second text box with moths between the two date. i,e i need to calculate the no of months between the two dates and I am accepting the data in yyyy/mm/dd format from the user.

Comment: slightly modified example http://jsfiddle.net/8haJX/1/ with months (I've used a function from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536379/difference-in-months-between-two-dates-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('textbox_id').value = difference;
```

where the variable `difference` is your calculated difference.