# Jquery Datepicker: Show multiple months (custom number) in multiple lines

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to display calendar using jquery datepicker with specified date range.
In one of the case, I would like to display 13 months in 3 lines.

I am able to display 12 months in 3 lines using: `numberOfMonths: [3,4]`

Please find the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9g82u2cc/) for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I researched quite a bit on this and was able to find the solution.

I used `numberOfMonths: [3,5]` and then with the help of [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536379/difference-in-months-between-two-dates-in-javascript) , tweaked the `monthDiff` logic to find the number of months to be removed from final calendar.

I found the class that `datepicker` uses to show each `month div`.
Then, used `slice` and `remove` functions to remove the unrequired months.

```
//Add 1 to difference as we require the month with endDate too
$("#datepicker > div > div.ui-datepicker-group").slice(requiredMonths - totalMonths + 1).remove();
```

Please find the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9g82u2cc/2/) for the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `numberOfMonths: [3,5]` you will see 15 months, but only will be available the days that you have defined.

Comment: Yeah that's correct but requirement is to show 13 months only not more

Comment: Then you can use `numberOfMonths: 13`, but it will display all the months in a single row.

Comment: No again that's not what i require

Comment: You can check the documentation: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-numberOfMonths

"Multiple types supported:

Number: The number of months to display in a single row.

Array: An array defining the number of rows and columns to display."