# month difference between two dates counting lastdate of month

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to find the month difference between two dates counting last date of month using javascript or jQuery.

ex:

```
01/03/2015 - 31/03/2015 - Month: 1

01/03/2015 - 30/03/2015 - Month: 0
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536379/difference-in-months-between-two-dates-in-javascript

Comment: This shouldn't be tagged with ruby-on-rails

Comment: any answers please ??

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript `Date:getMonth()` method:

```
Date startDate = "01/03/2015";
var startMonth = startDate.getMonth();
```

Further info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp)