# How to print total month between two dates in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have following script that displays table with the deals that happened Weekly .

I want to do it monthly and daily . I am having trouble doing monthly because all the month in a year wont have same interval .

**Script**

```
$('#test').click(function () {
  // Here are the two dates to compare
  var date1 = '29-10-2015';
  var date2 = '29-12-2015';
  var Targetvalue = parseFloat("1000000");
  var dealjson = '[{"dealdate":"25-12-2015","cost":200000},{"dealdate":"25-11-2015","cost":200000}]';

  // First we split the values to arrays date1[0] is the year, [1] the month and [2] the day
  date1 = date1.split('-');
  date2 = date2.split('-');

  // Now we convert the array to a Date object, which has several helpful methods
  date1 = new Date(date1[2], date1[1], date1[0]);
  date2 = new Date(date2[2], date2[1], date2[0]);
  var deals = JSON.parse(dealjson);
  var achieved = 0;

  date1_unixtime = parseInt(date1.getTime() / 1000);
  date2_unixtime = parseInt(date2.getTime() / 1000);

  // This is the calculated difference in seconds
  var timeDifference = date2_unixtime - date1_unixtime;

  // in Hours
  var timeDifferenceInHours = timeDifference / 60 / 60;

  // and finaly, in days :)
  var timeDifferenceInDays = timeDifferenceInHours / 24;
  var timeDifferenceInWeeks = Math.round(timeDifferenceInDays / 7);
  // alert(timeDifferenceInDays/7);
  TargetPerweek = Targetvalue / timeDifferenceInWeeks;
  TargetPerday = Targetvalue / timeDifferenceInDays;
  //Math.round(timeDifferenceInWeeks);
  TargetPerweek = Math.round(TargetPerweek * 100) / 100;

  var str = '<table class="table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable datatable responsive"> <thead><tr> <th>Week</th> <th>Target</th> <th>Achieved</th> </tr></thead>';
  var i = 0;

  while (date1 <= date2) {
    var next_week = new Date(date1);
    next_week.setDate(date1.getDate() + 7);
    achieved = 0;
    deals.forEach(function (deal) {
      var dealDate = deal.dealdate;
      dealDate = dealDate.split('-');
      dealDate = new Date(dealDate[2], dealDate[1], dealDate[0]);
      if (dealDate >= date1 && dealDate <= next_week) {
        achieved = achieved + deal.cost;
      }
    });
    i = i + 1;
    str = str + "<tr><th>Week" + i + "</th><td>" + TargetPerweek + "</td><td> " + achieved + "</td></tr>";
    date1 = next_week;
  }

  str = str + "</table>";
  $('.varianceData').html(str);
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/k2pkv17a/8/)

Basically if you observe this part of code

```
var str = '<table class="table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable datatable responsive"> <thead><tr> <th>Week</th> <th>Target</th> <th>Achieved</th> </tr></thead>';
var i = 0;

while (date1 <= date2) {
  var next_week = new Date(date1);
  next_week.setDate(date1.getDate() + 7);
  achieved = 0;
  deals.forEach(function (deal) {
    var dealDate = deal.dealdate;
    dealDate = dealDate.split('-');
    dealDate = new Date(dealDate[2], dealDate[1], dealDate[0]);
    if (dealDate >= date1 && dealDate <= next_week) {
      achieved = achieved + deal.cost;
    }
  });
  i = i + 1;
  str = str + "<tr><th>Week" + i + "</th><td>" + TargetPerweek + "</td><td> " + achieved + "</td></tr>";
  date1 = next_week;
}
```

You will get to know how I am building the weekwise table so I was just incrementing  the loop 7 times .

I want to show another table with Month Wise and Date wise

Comment: Can't you use var res = date1-date2?

Comment: return DisplayTo.getMonth() - DisplayFrom.getMonth()
       + (12 * (DisplayTo.getFullYear() - DisplayFrom.getFullYear()));

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536379/difference-in-months-between-two-dates-in-javascript

Comment: @suresh can you please create a Fiddle and give me example I will really thankful to you , Post it as an answer

Comment: hi vikram check it this link http://jsfiddle.net/bs0tcgax/7/

Comment: @suresh the fiddle is not working

Comment: Are you getting any alerts??

Comment: No @suresh not getting any alert