# Google Apps Script: Number of days between two dates after subtracting full months

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have two dates. I would like to know
  a) the number of full months between the two dates and
  b) the number of days after subtracting the full months.

Essentially what `DATEDIF(start_date, end_date, "m")` and `DATEDIF(start_date, end_date, "md")` would do if entered as a formula in Google Sheets.

Example:
Start date is 18 November 2015
End date is 3 March 2016

The number of full months between the two dates is 3.
The number of days after subtracting the full months is 12 + 3 = 15.

Does anyone have a solution how to calculate this in Google Apps Script?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2536445/512127

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to this post, Amit. I had already seen it; unfortunately, it only partially answers my question. I haven't seen a full answer in any of the forums I searched.

Comment: do show us first what you tried in javascript, like in the linked suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

To get the number of days after subtracting the full months, use this code:

```
function getNumberOfDaysBetweenTwoDatesSubstractFullMonths(startDate, endDate) {

  var startDay = startDate.getDate();
  var startMonth = startDate.getMonth();
  var startYear = startDate.getYear();

  var endDay = endDate.getDate();

  var startNumber = daysInMonth(startMonth, startYear) - startDay;
  var endNumber = endDay;

  return startNumber + endNumber;

}

function daysInMonth(month, year) {
  return new Date(year, month + 1, 0).getDate();
}
```

To check this in Google Sheets Script:

```
function TEST_days() {
  var d1 = new Date('18 November 2015');
  var d2 = new Date('3 March 2016');

  Logger.log(getNumberOfDaysBetweenTwoDatesSubstractFullMonths(d1, d2));

}
```