# How to generate a number of days in a month depending on the current month in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

**Goal:**
My end goal is to add the number of rows that is equal to the number of days in a month. For that I believe we should be using this method: insertRows(rowIndex, numRows).

**What I don't understand:**
However, I don't know how to calculate the number of days there are in a month of when the script was ran.

**What I was able to find:**
There were other questions on Stack Overflow that regards a similar issue, however most of them has to do with calculating the number of days between two dates (example question: [Google Apps Script: Number of days between two dates after subtracting full months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39643924/google-apps-script-number-of-days-between-two-dates-after-subtracting-full-mont)). In my case, I'm not using two dates, rather wanting to calculate the number of days depending on what the current month is.

Hope you can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the number of days in a month and want to insert the rows using the retrieved number.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  const year = 2021; // Please set the year.
  const month = 2; // Please set the month.

  const days = (new Date(year, month, 0)).getDate();
  console.log(days)  // You can check the result.

  // If you want to insert the rows from 1st row, you can use the following script.
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  sheet.insertRows(1, days);
}
```

- If you want to set the start row for inserting the rows, please modify `1` of `sheet.insertRows(1, days);`.

#### References:

- [Date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date)
- [insertRows(rowIndex, numRows)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertrowsrowindex,-numrows)

### Added:

About your following replying,

> Is there a way to do this dynamically without having to hardcode??

When you want to retrieve the number of days from this year and this month, how about the following script?

#### Sample script:

```js
const date = new Date();
const days = (new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0)).getDate();
console.log(days)
```

Comment: Hi Tanaike@-san, many thanks for answering very quickly. Is there a way to do this dynamically without having to hardcode??

Comment: @John Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your replying, although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about `Is there a way to do this dynamically without having to hardcode??`, I added a sample script in my answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your replying, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about the detail of your goal? By this, I would like to modify the answer.

Comment: Neat trick! TIL that the 'zero-ith' day (ie. `new Date(year, month, 0)`) gives you the last day of the month! Took me a minute to find it in the docs:

"Similarly, if any parameter underflows, it "borrows" from the higher positions. For example, new Date(2020, 5, 0) will return May 31st, 2020." - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date