# How I will get difference between two Month(YYYYMM) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date

```
var frommonth="201912";
var tomonth="201810";
```

From Above Two Month how i will get difference between two Month in JavaScript?

```
var date1 = new Date(fromdate);
var date2 = new Date(todate);
var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 

var fromYear=date1.getFullYear();
var toYear=date2.getFullYear();
var diffyear =toYear-fromYear;
```

Comment: Please don't tag javascript questions with java. Even though there is 'java' in the name 'javascript', the two languages are not the same. they are not even related.

Comment: The two dates probably won't be what you need. What date are you trying to specify?
Also, do you use moment.js? (Yes you tagged it but don't use it in your code...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`new Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) dont parse `YYYYMM`. It consider `201912` as year

So Use `match()` to parse `YYYYMM`

```js
var from = "201912";
var to = "201810";

function parseMonth(str) {
  return str.match(/(\d{4})(\d{2})/).splice(1).map(Number)
}

var [fromY, fromM] = parseMonth(from)
var [toY, toM] = parseMonth(to)

var result = (fromY - toY) * 12 + (fromM - toM)

console.log(result, 'months')
```

Comment: There's no need to convert to number, subtraction will do that anyway. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `frommonth` and `tomonth` to the function as parameters and can perform calculation of difference..

Here `new Date(frommonth.substring(0,4), frommonth.substring(4), 0)` denotes,

> -> `frommonth.substring(0,4)` => Getting the **year** from the string
>
> -> `frommonth.substring(4)` => Getting the **month** from the string
>
> -> `0` => Setting up date as 0.

And the same has been considered for `tomonth` as well..

Also `Math.round(timeDiff / (2e3 * 3600 * 365.25));` is made to consider the leap year as well..

```js
const frommonth = "201912"; 
const tomonth = "201810";


const diffInMonths = (end, start) => {
   var timeDiff = Math.abs(end.getTime() - start.getTime());
   return Math.round(timeDiff / (2e3 * 3600 * 365.25));
}

const result = diffInMonths(new Date(frommonth.substring(0,4), frommonth.substring(4), 0), new Date(tomonth.substring(0,4), tomonth.substring(4), 0));

//Diff in months
console.log(result);
```

Comment: 365.25 doesn't account for leap years.  There are no years that have 1/4 of a day in them.  Also 365.25 is the length of an average *Julian* year.  In the modern Gregorian calendar, the average length is 365.2425 days.  But still, no *average* year is what will happen in any given year.  (Rounding only helps when the result happens to align in your favor.  Over a large enough difference, the rounding will produce the wrong result.)

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint, I have made it as a reference from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54706607/7785337 and made this change for leap year support. But as I am not well versed about the date, timediff , I may be slightly wrong with it.. Happy  to learn from you about it.. Thanks !!..