# How do I check if the time between two dates exceeds a certain number of months?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I have an app where a user can select two dates (a from date and a to date) and the time between the dates should not exceed 4 months. A user can select the day, month and year for each date. Is there some kind of logic I could use to achieve this, so that an error is returned if the date range is over 4 months. Each input as an integer. For example, a start date of March 31st 2019 would be: `from_date_day = 31` `from_date_month = 3` and `from_date_year = 2019`

For example, I something like this would kind of work:

```
((Math.abs($('#to_date_month').val() - $('#from_date_month').val()) > 2) && $('#from_date_day').val() <= $('#to_date_day').val()
  return "error"
```

The problem with this code is that it doesn't work when the dates straddle two different years. I'm using coffeescript, but a solution in jquery or js would also work.

Comment: What is the expected format of the inputs?

Comment: @Shiny they are all integers. i've edited the question.

Comment: For calculating with dates I would always suggest to use [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) which makes it way more easier dealing with different years, February 29th, etc.

Comment: Don't use Moment for something like this. Its a massive library.

Comment: Use this: `const months = (to_year - from_year) * 12 + (to_month - from_month) + (to_day - from_day) / 31;` The result will be a float, and if it is `< 4`, it's less than four months.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference in Months between two dates in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536379/difference-in-months-between-two-dates-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend creating two Javascript **Date** objects of those two dates. This can be done by feeding the year, the month and finally the day to the constructor of the Date object.

e.g.

```
var startDate = new Date(2019, 1, 16); // January the 16th
var endDate = new Date(2019, 3, 30); // March the 30th
```

Using the `.getTime()` function of the Date object you can get the number of milliseconds passed since 1.1.1970. If you calculate the difference between those two numbers, wrap it inside `Math.abs()` and divide that number by `1000`, `60`, `60` and finally `24` you get the number of days. If this number is bigger than ~120, the range is more than four months.

```
console.log(Math.abs(startDate.getTime() - endDate.getTime()) / 1000/60/60/24);
```

In your use case the Date object could be set like this:

```
var startDate = new Date(parseInt($('#from_date_year').val()), parseInt($('#from_date_month').val()), parseInt($('#from_date_day').val()));
```