# Difference between two dates 6 months should not be more than 6 months

Tags: javascript

I need to find the difference between two dates. If the difference is greater than 6 then display a message in Java Script.

I tried below logic but somehow it is not working.

```
var sFromDate = new Date(Mon Jun 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0400);
var sToDate = new Date(Mon Nov 30 2020 23:59:59 GMT-0500);
var diff = sToDate.getTime() - sFromDate.getTime();
diff = diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30);
if (diff > 6) {
    alert('Not more than 6 months')
}
```

In the above example. I am still getting the alert even the range is within 6 months.

Can someone help me in finding the logic the difference between 2 dates should not be more than 6 months.

Comment: Not every month is 30 days long.

Comment: Your date expressions are illegal.

Comment: Check the [syntax for `new Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date). Use commas or strings.

Comment: 6.10138850308642 > 6, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4312956/4610740). In your case the code would be-

```js
function monthDiff(dateFrom, dateTo) {
 return dateTo.getMonth() - dateFrom.getMonth() + 
   (12 * (dateTo.getFullYear() - dateFrom.getFullYear()))
}

const sFromDate = new Date("Mon Jan 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0400");
const sToDate = new Date("Mon Nov 30 2020 23:59:59 GMT-0500");

const diff = monthDiff(sFromDate, sToDate);

if (diff > 6) alert('Not more than 6 months');

console.log('Diff in months: ', diff);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the first date and add 6 months, then check that against the second date:

```js
const date1 = new Date('Mon Jun 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0400');
const date2 = new Date('Mon Nov 30 2020 23:59:59 GMT-0500');
const plus6Months = new Date(date1.getYear(), date1.getMonth()+6, date1.getDay());

if (date2.getTime() > plus6Months.getTime())
  console.log('dates are more than 6 months apart');
else if (date2.getTime() < plus6Months.getTime())
  console.log('dates are less than 6 months apart');
else 
  console.log('dates are exactly 6 months apart');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var sFromDate = new Date(Mon Jun 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0400);
var sToDate = new Date(Mon Nov 30 2020 23:59:59 GMT-0500);
var months = (sToDate.getFullYear() - sFromDate.getFullYear()) * 12;
months -= sFromDate.getMonth();
months += sToDate.getMonth();
if (months > 6) {
    alert('Not more than 6 months')
}
```

Comment: This could benefit from an explanation

Comment: ... especially as it isn't valid JS.  Did you mean to pass strings to the Date constructor instead?  Did you mean to *call* `getFullYear`?